# Most frequent element in a Binary Search Tree

Tags: algorithm

How can we find the most frequently occurring element in a BST? I thought of implementing it using hash-map. Is there any easy way?

Comment: Please note that `the most frequent occuring element` implies that you allow duplicates. If every key were unique, all keys in the tree would have a frequency of **1**. (and non-existing keys a frequency of zero obviously)

Answer (score 8):

This problem is equivalent to finding the most frequent element in a sorted array - the same algorithm applies:

- Start the counter at zero
- Increment the counter while the current element is equal to the prior one
- When you find a different element, compare the counter to the current best run; replace if necessary
- Continue to the next element

The only difference is that instead of an array traversal with a loop you do a tree traversal with a recursive function. In both cases the algorithm is linear in time in the number of elements in the tree. If the tree is balanced, the algorithm requires `O(LogN)` space on the invocation stack.

Comment: since its a BST. It cant be assumed to be balanced.

Comment: @SrikarAppal He's not assuming its balanced, he's just giving what the time complexity of the algorithm would be _if it was balanced_.  Although, to be fair, he should also have given the complexity for a completely linear tree (maximally unbalanced).

Comment: Yes he is not assuming. but my point is not that. For a maximally unbalanced BST the space taken in this case would be `O(n)` on stack, which is as good as doing inorder traversal of BST, storing elements in an array and scanning it linearly to find most frequent element. Nothing wrong in either approach I guess...

Answer (score 2):

It can be done in more than one ways -

1. Do a [Inorder Traversal](http://leetcode.com/2010/04/binary-search-tree-in-order-traversal.html) of the BST. This would give you a sorted list of the elements. Do a Linear traversal to find the most repeated element. `time O(n) space O(n)`
2. Hashtable like you said. Do any of the [DFS traversals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Depth-first_2) of the BST. Insert each element into a hashtable with count set to 1. If element already exists then increment count+1. Then do a traversal of the hashtable to figure out the frequently occurring element.  Worst case time `O(n)` and space `O(n)` but in practice this approach should take less space if the dataset has lots of duplicates.

Comment: Would rather do it while doing inorder traversal instead of going through elements one more time.

Comment: @RajHassani the second case leads to less space utilization which could be desirable.

Answer (score 1):

That is the cleanest way to do it:

- init a hash map, which maps a value to its number of occurrence.
- Iterate the BST in-order:

  - hash[node.value] += 1

---

You can do it in place (`O(1)` additional memory complexity):

keep 2 `O(1)` variables indicate the max number of occurrences and the element, iterate the tree in-order which promise you it is in increasing manner, and update the element maximum occurrences:

```
curmax = 0
maxnode = null
for each node in BST.inorder():
    if next.value == node.value:
        max ++
    else:
        max = 1
    if max > curmax:
        curmax  = max
        maxnode = node
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use modified inorder traversal as said and keep track of the previous element.

```
TreeNode prev = null;
int count = 1, max = 0;
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();


private void inorder(TreeNode root) {
    if (root == null) return;
    inorder(root.left);
    if (prev != null) {
        if (root.val == prev.val)
            count++;
        else
            count = 1;
    }
    if (count > max) {
        max = count;
        list.clear();
        list.add(root.val);
    } else if (count == max) {
        list.add(root.val);
    }
    prev = root;
    inorder(root.right);
}
```

As inorder traversal gives us elements in ascending order this technique is useful and the list here will contain those elements.